# Evaluate the limit involving trace of a Matrix

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, limits

> Let $A=[a_{ij}]_{n×n}$ be a square Matrix such that $a_{ij}=(3i+2)5^{-j}$ then the value of $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\operatorname{tr}(A^n))^{\frac{1}{n}}, n\in \mathbb{N}$$

I can see the pattern of elements in the matrix $A$ but I can't calculate $A^n.$ Also, I don't know any property of trace that relates, $\operatorname{tr}(A^n)$ to $\operatorname{tr}(A)$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you estimate the entries in the matrix?  There’s a lot of negative powers of $5$ hanging around.

Comment: This is also a rank-one matrix, so it has at most one nonzero eigenvalue.  Then observe that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @MichaelBurr what is rank of a Matrix?? And how to find it's characteristic equation coz without how will I find it's eigenvalues

Comment: *Hint.* Since $A$ is a rank-one matrix, $\operatorname{tr}(A^n)=\operatorname{tr}(A)^n$.

Comment: @user1551 can you pls elaborate?? I have not studied rank of a Matrix till now...can you pls tell what is rank and how to check rank of matrices??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we multiply a matrix $A$ by itself,
$\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & ..... \\ a_{12} & a_{22} & .... \\ .... \end{bmatrix}$ to get$\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & ..... \\ A_{12} & A_{22} & .... \\ .... \end{bmatrix}$, $A_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj}$.
Therefore $A_{tt} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(3t+2)}{5^t}\frac{(3k+2)}{5^k}$ which is equal to $S_{n}\frac{(3t+2)}{5^t}$. Thus, trace of $A^2$ will be $\sum_{t=1}^n A_{tt}$ which is $S^2_{n}$.

Similarly if we multiply $\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & ..... \\ A_{12} & A_{22} & .... \\ .... \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & ..... \\ a_{12} & a_{22} & .... \\ .... \end{bmatrix}$ to get $\begin{bmatrix} B_{11} & B_{12} & ..... \\ B_{12} & B_{22} & .... \\ .... \end{bmatrix}$ ,
$B_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}a_{kj}$. $B_{tt} = \sum_{k=1}^n A_{tk}a_{kt} = \sum_{k=1}^n (\sum_{z=1}^n a_{tz}a_{zk})a_{kt} = \sum_{k=1}^n S_{n} \frac{(3t+2)}{5^t}\frac{(3k+2)}{5^k} = S_{n}^2\frac{(3t+2)}{5^t}$.

Thus trace of matrix $A^3$ is $S{n}^3$.

By this the pattern can be observed and if we try for higher powers we get that trace of $A^n$ is $S_{n}^n$.Then the question simply reduces to $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(3i+2)}{5^i}.$

(Sorry for the bad formatting I am still new to this)

Edit: Lets assume a 3 by 3 matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $A^2$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 1*1 + 2*4 + 3*7 & 1*2 + 2*5 + 3*8  & 1*3 + 2*6 + 3*9 \\ 4*1 + 5*4 + 6*7 & 4*2 + 5*5 + 6*8 & 4*3 + 5*6 + 6*9 \\ 7*1 + 8*4 + 9*7 & 7*2 + 8*5 + 9*8 & 7*3 + 8*6 + 9*9 \end{bmatrix}$

So in general to get the $A^2_{ij}$ element we multiply the elements of the $ith$ row and the $jth$ column. Mathematically we can represent it as $A^2_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj}$ as $A^2_{ij}$ is nothing but $a_{i1}a_{ij} + a_{i2}a_{2j}.......$. So in the question $A^2_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj}$. To find the trace, we need the diagonal elements $i=j=$(Let's say)$t$. So $A^2_{tt}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{tk}a_{kt} =  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(3t+2)}{5^t}\frac{(3k+2)}{5^k}$(From the definition of $a_{ij}=\frac{(3i+2)}{5^j}$). Assume  $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(3k+2)}{5^k}$ to be $S_{n}$. Then $A^2_{tt}$ is simply $\frac{(3t+2)}{5^t}S_{n}$. The trace is summation of the diagonal elements $A^2{tt} =  \sum_{t=1}^n \frac{(3t+2)}{5^t}S_{n}$ which is $S_{n}^2$.

Hope this helps in better understanding and you can take it from here!

Comment: Can you pls elaborate a little bit more

Comment: Which part do you need me to elaborate?

Comment: You've extensively used mathematical language...can you pls give some examples to support your statements as I'll be able to grasp better...like those summation results

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad i hav editted my answer and added an example, hope it helps.

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad could you also mention where you found this question. Thanks

Comment: I found this question on a local telegram channel

Answer (score 2):

Note that $A=uv^T$ where $u=\pmatrix{3(1)+2\\ 3(2)+2\\ \vdots\\ 3n+2}$ and $v^T=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5^2}&\cdots&\frac{1}{5^n}}$. Therefore $\operatorname{tr}(A)=v^Tu>0$ and
$$
A^n
=\underbrace{(uv^T)(uv^T)\cdots(uv^T)}_{n\text{ copies}}
=u\,\underbrace{(v^Tu)(v^Tu)\cdots(v^Tu)}_{n-1\text{ copies}}\,v^T
=(v^Tu)^{n-1}uv^T.
$$
Consequently, $\operatorname{tr}(A^n)=(v^Tu)^{n-1}\operatorname{tr}(uv^T)=(v^Tu)^n=\operatorname{tr}(A)^n$. Hence $\left(\operatorname{tr}(A^n)\right)^{1/n}=\operatorname{tr}(A)$.